# Is it possible to comment an action in AA Workbench?

Tags: automationanywhere

I'd like to comment an action in the *Actions List* so that it'll skip the execution. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the action/line and disable.
That will skip the line from execution.

In addition, if you want to write a comment in your task you can use **comment** command.